# Entity Framework : Find returns null after stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which inserts data into a table. I'm querying immediately after the stored procedure statement with `.Find` to see if the insert happened, and it's returning null. If I query later with another `DbContext`, it's there, so it's as if that I need to refresh the context.

Some sample code:

```
string name = "Awesome book";
string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

// Entity Framework context
BooksDb db = new BooksDb();

// call to stored procedure 
db.insert_book(id, name);

// check if it's there
book b = db.books.Find(id); // b is null
```

Do I need to refresh something to I get to find the item with id that I'm looking for?

Update: I figured it out thanks to the comments below. I was actually looking for the id which I thought I was inserting, however the stored procedure had auto id creation. So basically I was querying something which didn't exist. :)

Comment: please, show your SP and how are you calling it

Comment: Seems like you need to call SaveChanges after the sp to synchronizes the changes in the context's  with the data store.

Comment: I don't think so, Aldo

Comment: What does `insert_book` do (*can you show the code*)? `BooksDb.books` should be a `DbSet<T>`, it seems your call to `insert_book` does not attach the added book to the `DbSet<T>` in memory and it will not hit the database until after you call `SaveChanges` on the `DbContext` so that is why it can't be found.

Comment: Consider [mapping the context's CUD actions to stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468673(v=vs.113).aspx). You'll get much for free.

Comment: Ok - so I'll mark this as fixed now. Basically I was being incredibly stupid and querying the id, however the SP had the Auto ID create in it. Thanks a lot folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the stored procedure, I figured that it had auto id creation, so I wasn't actually querying the item that I thought I had the id. `SaveChanges` being called on `DBContext` makes sure that it lights up as well.